# How can I get AzureDevOps build variables information through the Rest API's?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a tool [aztr](https://github.com/loganwol/aztr) that summarizes the Azure Build/Release pipeline test results. A recent requirement has come up to save the incoming variable information and the summary information for consumption outside of the tool (say a csv file).

Now on the Release pipelines side the [Release API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) provides all the details about the variables passed into the Release. I want the same functionality to be available on the Build side as well but the [Build API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1), does not provide that functionality. Is there a different API, I need to use to get the variables passed into the build?

Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could list the custom build variables via this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version=6.0
```

In addition, they are some predefined variables in the variable and they are [DevOps Services system variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables-devops-services), we cannot list them via this api.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I am wondering if the build definition variables change from build to build, how do I get the specific value for a build?

Comment: Found it, the get build api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0, returns a parameters collection.